# PowerShell 2.0 via C#, return values are empty?

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0, exchange-server

I'm using C# to call Exchange 2010 PowerShell methods and I've just encountered a snag.

The Collection returned by the Execute method don't have a BaseObject. I can use .Properties["PropertyName"], but it seems that all those values are string values. Not very practical for file size, Guids and so on.

Reading http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2010/01/07/how-objects-are-sent-to-and-from-remote-sessions.aspx, it seems that this is normal, and the types I have are Deserialized.Namespace.TypeName.

I'm looking for a way to serialize them back into a live object that I can use properties and so on. I have the appropriate DLL and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can get any property I want, but it needs to be in the PS script I invoke remotely.

I figured it out while querying PowerShell via direct Remote powershell, not with the Exchange namespace.

Here is an example

```
$spsite | Select Id, Url,
          @{ Name = "Owner"; Expression = { $_.Owner.UserLogin } }
```

This works perfectly, I can then use

```
psResult.Members["Owner"].Value as string
```

to get the owner

Answer (score 0):

You can get the orginal object like this:

PS bit:

```
$results = $MyCustomCollection
```

C# bit:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSObject>
results = pipeline.Invoke();

CustomCollection theCustumCollection
    = (CustomCollection )runspace.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable("results");
```

you do have to make sure that the only thing returned is that object and nothing else;
so put anything that would return anything to null;